# CC1125 tramsmit data from the nanosatellite to ground station

Tags: rf, antenna, signal, modulation, texas-instruments

does the chip cc1125 can transmit data between nanosatellites to ground stations the distance between them is up to 400km with band frequency UHF from uplink and vhf of the downlink.

- If yes can use the transmitter and receiver with mode half duplex with a data rate is 4000kps?
- If yes can add a bloc of amplifier signal between the chip cc1125 and antenna to achieve that the signal can propagate a long distance of 400km
  -If yes which kind of modulation should be used
  -If yes better to add two blocs in the design of my own board once from the transceiver and the second from the receiver
  please response
  regards

Comment: uff. You're going to spend tens of thousands of Euros to get a nanosatellite into space, and all that you can do to communicate with it is based on asking strangers on the internet whether a couple-of-dollars IC is the right thing, betraying an utter lack of background in communications engineering. So, the answer here is: do not shoot up expensive space debris. Buy a ready-made modem. Cobbling this together and hoping for the best is *not* an option in satellite links.

Comment: Any signal propagates an infiinite distance. so, the question "does it propagate 400km" can be answered with "yes" for literally any transmitter. The question whether you can communicate with it over that distance is a completely different one, and depends on its noise figure, its transmit power, the noise figure of your ground station, the antenna gains, the frequencies you're assigned to use, processing loss on the ground, and the transmit power of your ground end. I promise you you won't build a 400 kbps link from scratch on the first attempt going into space.

Comment: There's by the way a name for what you're about to build that I've learned from actual satellite engineers, and that's "temporarily interfering, uncontrollably deorbiting pre-designated debris", and it's not a compliment.